# Markdown to Word/PDF converter for Linux

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, markdown

Does anyone know of a good Markdown to Word COnverter?  It would be great if it also converts to PDF.

Comment: I'd think it would make more sense to go through HTML as an intermediate step, because that's what Markdown is designed for.

Comment: Pandoc is now capable of converting Markdown to DOCX directly.

Answer (score 11):

It seems [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert Markdown to PDF (via LaTeX). Converting to Word should be possible by converting to ODT or RTF first.

Comment: Pandoc is now capable of converting Markdown to DOCX directly.

Comment: Directly [from Markdown to PDF](http://pandoc.org/demos.html) would be `pandoc Manual.md --latex-engine=xelatex -o Manual.pdf`. If you get _pandoc: xelatex not found. xelatex is needed for pdf output._:  `sudo apt install texlive-xetex`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are no automatic tools to do that without having to use workaround that can result in serious glitches (ex: markdown -> odt -> docx).

I have found that generating a html, then doing a copy/paste into a word document looks surprisingly good.

Answer (score 1):

Byword is a mac app that converts to word and PDF. It also has some great features that make writing markdown even easier.

Also if you want to style your documents - I can recommend the Marked app which allows you to apply css to your .md files and export to a range of formats.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS there is also the free [mou app](http://mouapp.com/) which allows you to edit Markdown. Using the print function you can output the rendered document as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for a **Linux** solution, here is one:

```
pandoc README.md -o README.pdf
```

Comment: This program was suggested 7 years ago.....

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [ReText editor](https://github.com/retext-project/retext). It is included in Ubuntu Linux and probably other Linux distributions. It gives you a live preview of your markdown. And it has export functionality for PDF, Office(ODT) and HTML. Just open your markdown file and go to File -> Export -> PDF/ODT/HTML. You should be able to open both HTML and ODT in MS Word.